# Anti-freeze or non-freeze faucet leaking a lot from the top metal cap

Tags: water, leak, faucet, hose, leaks

I have two outdoor antifreeze faucets that are both leaking from the top metal cap. As shown in the pictures. [image][[image: enter image description here]][image]

I tried tightening it and using teflon tape then tightening it, but none works. I can get access of the other side of the pipe for one faucet, but for other faucet, the other side of the pipe is behind dry wall.

Any suggestion on what less-invasive solutions I should try next?

Comment: that cap is supposed to contain an anti-siphon valve. .... did you remove something from inside the cap? ..... why did it not occur to you to take a picture of the inside of the cap?

Comment: No idea, we didn't do anything, must be previous owner. I did see there is some kind of white ring/valve for the other faucet, it doesn't completely cover the water hole, is that the valve you are talking about? And can I get these valves easily from hardware store? How can I make sure I get the right valve without bringing this unit to the store?

Comment: `How can I make sure I get the right valve without bringing this unit to the store?`  ... think a little .... what else can you take to the store with you?

Comment: Do both valves look the same? Then you could just take the piece from the other valve with you and see if it's the same they got.

Comment: The units look the same. I can take the white ring and get the same one and try. Though both faucets are leaking as mentioned in the description.